# C++ Visual studio reporting "not all paths return a value"

Tags: visual-c++

I'm creating a rock paper scissors game for an assignment and one of my functions is returning a warning saying "not all control paths return a value". I'm assuming the issue is with the switch statement but I'm not sure as everything in the statement is returning a value.

Here's the code if anyone can help:

```
int GameChoice()
{
    bool loop = true;
    while (loop == true)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Choose one of the following:" << endl;
        cout << "[1] Rock" << endl;
        cout << "[2] Paper" << endl;
        cout << "[3] Scissors" << endl;
        cout << "[4] Lizard" << endl;
        cout << "[5] Spock" << endl;
        cout << "[6] End Game" << endl;
        cout << "Enter Selection: ";
        int UserChoice;
        cin >> UserChoice;
        cout << endl;

        switch (UserChoice)
        {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
            loop = false;
            return UserChoice;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Incorrect choice" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a code analysis warning, static analysis is notoriously unreliable with the halting problem having no solution.  Project > Properties > Code Analysis > General > "Use Microsoft Code Analysis" = No and it will stop complaining.  Or tweak the code, it doesn't actually ever use the loop = false assignment.  `for (;;) {}` is loop-forever-until-break-or-return syntax that the analyzer understands well.

Comment: I've tweaked it to use the ```for (;;) {}``` as a loop which solved the issue, so thank you for that. and is the false = loop assignment not used the input is 6?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can ignore the warning.

In fact, before the first iteration of the while-loop is complete you will reach either `return UserChoice;` or `return 0;`.

I guess the compiler expects a return statement after the loop.

Comment: It runs fine without the warning but the assignment marks you down for having errors or warnings i believe, so I'm just wondering if there's a way to get rid of it.

Comment: Just add a ``return 0;`` after the while loop. I didn't test it, but that should do the job